# prolog if else statement with swish

Tags: prolog

```
odd_even(X) :-
  (
     X < 10, 
     myOdd(1, X)
  ; 
     myOdd(1, 9), 
     myEven(10, X)
  ).
```

is this statement considered as if else statement in prolog since what i understand in prolog if statement should be like this. ( condition -> then_clause ; else_clause )
using swish prolog

Answer (score 1):

> Is this statement considered as if else statement in Prolog since what I understand in Prolog if statement should be like this. ( condition -> then_clause ; else_clause).

No, the code you gave is not of the form `( condition -> then_clause ; else_clause)` as there is no `->` operator.

Perhaps you meant to write

```
odd_even(X) :-
  (
     X < 10
  ->
     myOdd(1, X)
  ; 
     myOdd(1, 9), 
     myEven(10, X)
  ).
```

Since your predicate name hints at one thought and your code does what I don't know, I won't even try to understand or fix this.

Also, notice that I reformatted your source code so it is easier to comprehend with a quick glance.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is the basic Prolog pattern to replace an if-then-else construct . Prolog calls the first clause : if yes true that X < 10 the ! in that first clause stops the second clause from being used . If the first clause determined that it is not true that `X< 10` then the second clause is used .

```
odd_even(X)
:-
X < 10 ,
! ,
myOdd(1,X)
.

odd_even(X)
:-
! ,
myOdd(1,9) , 
myEven(10,X)
.
```

Comment: Your contributions are very welcome, but I keep wondering about the strange formatting. Is there a reason you don't indent your clause bodies? This is one major factor why I hesitate to upvote your contributions. (Although in this particular case I wouldn't upvote because of the cuts, which in this context are strictly inferior to `_ -> _ ; _`.)

Comment: Yes of course there is an reason I do not indent the bodies .
Yes of course there is an reason I do not put an space after every comma I use .

The rigid insistence on exactly similar coding style in the "Prolog community" is excessive .

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This solution is the basic Prolog pattern to replace an _if-then-else_ construct .  Prolog calls the first clause : if yes true that `X < 10` the `!` in that first clause  stops the second clause from being used . If the first clause determined that it is not true that` X< 10` then the second clause is used .

Comment: Please add all explanation **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: Thanks for Your help Nico .

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie the cut is okay IMO in this case because the X cannot be variable in the < comparison . Therefore there is no _further_ loss of generality : the < comparison has already required the X variable to be ground .

Comment: The first cut is OK, but I find this kind of code much clearer with `_ -> _ ; _`. The second cut is useless and a sign of magical thinking rather than understanding of what cuts do.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Use of the `_ -> _` is equivalent to use of the cut as far as logical purity is concerned . The second cut is indeed optional but not magical thinking rather provided for documentation-like purposes : it emphasizes that the clause is part of an case analysis .